# Laravel References 2e en 3th level

Tags: php, laravel, reference, foreign-key-relationship

I have 3 tables.

**Table news (hasMany Writers)**

```
id
name
```

**Table Writers (hasMany News and BelongsTo Country)**

```
id
Name
country_id
```

**Table Countries (hasMany Writers)**

```
id
name
```

**Now I want to display this in a view:**

```
Name(news), Name(Writer), Name(Country)
```

**I only can display:**

```
Name(news), Name(Writer), country_id
```

How do I display the country name?

Comment: Assuming you've got a News object, $news->writer->country->name should work. Maybe some code of your Writer model where you declare the relationship to the Country model would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `TableWriter` model you should have a function 'country'.

```
public function country() {
  return $this->belongsTo('TableWriter');
}
```

The the country_id should be the `id` of the country and you can do `$tableWriter->country()->name` where `$tablewriter` is an instance of your `TableWriter`.

So with the above in `app/TableWriter.php` you should be able do do something like:

```
$tableWriter = AppName\TableWriter::first();
echo $tableWriter->country()->name;
```

This should echo the counter name of the first TableWriter.